# Shared Preferences - HashSet<String>/Set<String> limit/max size

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, hashset

I'm using SharedPreferences to store a `Set` of strings, using `.putStringSet()`, but I can not get more then 99 items from it using `.getStringSet()`.

- Is there a size limit for `HashSet<String>/Set<String>`?
- If yes, how can I increase/change it?

See the code below:

```
//Always return 99 items.
private Set<String> getIdentifers(){
    Set<String> identifiers = preferences.getStringSet("my_ids", new HashSet<String>());
    return new HashSet<String>(identifiers);
}

//`Identifiers` contains 100 items.
private Boolean saveIdentifier(Set<String> identifiers){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putStringSet("my_ids", identifiers);
    return editor.commit(); 
}

//`Identifiers` show 100 items on Android Studio Debug Console after added `Identifier`to it.
public Boolean addIdentifierToMemory(String identifier){
    Set<String>identifiers = getIdentifers(); //99 items
    identifiers.add(identifier); //99 items
    return savePurchasedProductsIdentifier(identifiers); //100 items
}
```

Comment: Did you try storage data with a content provider? Shared Preferences are not meant for that.

Comment: Either that or a database.